# RequiredFieldValidator and regularexpressionvalidator don't work

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, validation

I have the below code in one of my "C#" aspx pages.  When I click on cmdPassword it fires the event even if the textbox is empty.  Why isn't either validation stopping it?

```
<tr>
  <td align="left" valign="top">Password:</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">
    <asp:TextBox id="txtPassword" ValidationGroup="vgPassword" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" Width="200px" MaxLength=15 textmode="Password" />
            <br /><font class="pagetext_7">(between 6 and 15 characters long)</font>
            <br />
            <asp:literal id="litPassword" runat="server"></asp:literal>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="left">
      <asp:Button ID="cmdPassword" CausesValidation="true" runat="server" OnClick="cmdPassword_Click" validationgroup="vgPassword" style="color:#284E98;background-color:White;border-color:#507CD1;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Verdana;font-size:0.8em;" Text="Submit" height="20px" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"  validationgroup="vgPassword" />
      <asp:regularexpressionvalidator id="valPassword" runat="server" validationgroup="vgPassword" errormessage="Password must be between 6 and 15 characters long" validationexpression="^.{6,15}$" controltovalidate="txtPassword"></asp:regularexpressionvalidator>
    </td>
   </tr>
```

UPDATE:  I just added this code below to the button click event.

```
protected void cmdPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (txtPassword.Text.Length == 0)
  {
    litPassword.Text = "<font color='red'>Password cannot be blank.</font>";
  }
  else
  {
    //Password update code
  }
}
```

Does anyone see any issues with doing it this way?

Comment: You are missing the validationgroup in the TextBox.

Comment: Hi Kami,  Thanks for the reply.  I added the validation group to the text box and the button click event still fires.

Comment: remove CausesValidation="true"

Comment: I copied your aspx code from above into a new project and it worked fine.

Comment: @Jerry Warra: Your code is working properly it's firing client side validation when text box is empty or Password is too short. Kinda there could some other issue that could have disable your client side validation. This part of code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `regularexpressionvalidator` not fired if text box is empty.So nothing wrong with your code.if you want it also check it even your text box empty you have to to change your regular expression.

Comment: Agreed but why doesn't the RequiredFieldValidator stop the click event from firing?

Comment: just add this to your button it will work

CausesValidation="True" not to text box

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it

```
protected void cmdPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (txtPassword.Text.Length == 0)
   {
     litPassword.Text = "<font color='red'>Password cannot be blank.</font>";
   }
   else
   {
    //Password update code
   }
}
```